# Can I navigate relationships between CICS resouces from Ansible?

Tags: ansible, graphql, cics

I've been getting started with the [CICS collection](https://galaxy.ansible.com/ibm/ibm_zos_cics) on Ansible Galaxy. I've been using it to do things like request individual resources, but I can't see a way of traversing relationships like you would do in CICS' CMCI GraphQL API.

Does the collection have that ability?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the CICS collection doesn't have the ability to use the CMCI GraphQL API. It purely uses the CMCI REST API which just deals with one resource type at a type.

However, that doesn't mean you can't use the CMCI GraphQL API to CICS from Ansible! That API is generally a bit more understandable and you can build up queries using GraphiQL without needing a special collection. Then, you can use Ansible's built-in `uri` module to send GraphQL requests and get information out of the response.

### Simple query

Here, for example, is a simple playbook and accompanying GraphQL query to get the structure of a CICSplex with its CICS regions, and print out the result. The important part is the `query` key being added to the `body` of the request.

`playbook1.yml`:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:

  - name: Get data from CICS
    register: result
    uri:
      url: https://my.cicsplex:12345/graphql/
      method: POST
      body_format: json
      body:
        query: '{{ lookup("file", "./queries/topology_query.graphql") }}' #  GraphQL query is passed here

  - name: Print out response
    debug:
      msg: '{{ result.json }}'
```

`queries/topology_query.graphql`:

```
{
  cicsplexes {
    name
    regions {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

---

### Adding variables to the query

Of course, you probably want to parameterise the query. You *can* do that using Jinja templating in Ansible. Here's a playbook and accompanying GraphQL query to find a particular region name (named `MYREGION`, in the `vars`) across all connected CICSplexes.

`playbook2.yml`:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:
    regionName: MYREGION

  tasks:
  - name: Get data from CICS
    register: result
    uri:
      url: https://my.cicsplex:12345/graphql/
      method: POST
      body_format: json
      body:
        query: '{{ lookup("template", "./templates/single_region_query.graphql.j2") }}' # template instead of plain file

  - name: Print out response
    debug:
      msg: '{{ result.json }}'
```

`templates/single_region_query.graphql.j2`:

```
{
  cicsplexes {
    name
    region(name: "{{ regionName }}") { # this variable will be expanded by Ansible
      name
    }
  }
}
```

---

### Adding variables to the query - a better way

However, I get a bit leery about templating. It seems fairly prone to injection problems, be they malicious or just accidental, when vars are coming in from elsewhere! Even writing the example above, I missed getting the quotes right. So I'd prefer to use GraphQL's built-in variable support to sanitise variables better.

In CICS' CMCI GraphQL API, you can supply variables using the `variables` key in the body of the request you send to CICS, alongside the existing `query` key.

Here you see the `regionName` variable being supplied in the body, and then the same variable (referred to as `$regionName`) in the GraphQL query.

`playbook3.yml`:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:
    regionName: MYREGION

  tasks:

  - name: Get data from plex
    register: result
    uri:
      url: https://my.cicsplex:12345/graphql/
      method: POST
      body_format: json
      body:
        query: '{{ lookup("file", "./queries/single_region_query.graphql") }}' # plain file, not template
        variables:
          regionName: "{{ regionName }}" # variables will get passed to CICS

  - name: Print out response
    debug:
      msg: '{{ result.json }}'
```

`queries/single_region_query.graphql`:

```
query searchForRegion ($regionName: String!) { # query declares used variables
  cicsplexes {
    name
    region(name: $regionName) { # GraphQL expands the variable here at query execution time
      name
    }
  }
}
```